# Not a file, not a folder, but a hard link(?) to /bin from another partition - scared to delete

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs, symfony

I have a not-quite-folder not-quite-file on my file system. It is an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I have a script that runs nightly that picks up a file (/ebsvol/dead-drop/sync) and moves it to (/ebsvol/dead-drop/sync) using Robo, which in turn is using Symfony's Filesystem rename() method (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#rename).

```
  const CANARY_PATH = '/ebsvol/dead-drop/sync';
  const CANARY_WORKING_PATH = '/ebsvol/dead-drop/~sync';
...
  $this->taskFilesystemStack()
    ->rename(self::CANARY_PATH, self::CANARY_WORKING_PATH)
    ->run();
```

Something is going awry in the script or with this code, though that's not really why I'm here. The result and cleanup is why I'm here. :)

The result is that the ~sync "file" is created, however it is actually... a hard link to /bin? This is where things get fishy. My `ls -ial` looks like this:

```
3276803 -rw-rw-r--  1 configbot configbot  125 Jul  4 00:30 '~sync'
```

So it's just a text file, so let's try cat...

```
$ cat ~sync
cat: /bin: Is a directory
```

Uhh, OK.

```
$ cd ~sync
```

...changes my prompt to /bin, and doing an ls, it's surely bin. Incidentally, `ls -ial` on my root volume shows that /bin is iNode 12.

*This has happened to me once in the past, and I just did `rm -rf ~sync` which hosed my entire server and I had to rebuild. So I'm trying to avoid that.*

**How do I get rid of this weird ~sync file/folder/symlink/hardlink without trashing /bin?**

Some additional info:

- `/ebsvol` is a separate EBS volume than `/` (i.e. separate hard drives/partitions!)
- I think if it's a hard link in some weird way, `rm ~sync` might work. But wouldn't it show identical iNode numbers?
- I will take a snapshot of both volumes before I attempt anything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to name a file beginning with a tilde if you intend to access it with a shell like bash. The reason being that it interprets the tilde as meaning that you want to access a user's home directory.

Thus, bash (and other shells) expand `~` to the current user's home directory, and expand `~sync` to the home directory of the user named sync.

It turns out that your Ubuntu system has a system user named `sync` whose home directory is `/bin`. Thus when you try to access `~sync` from the shell, it expands this to the user's home directory, and you start getting odd messages. And when you ran `rm -rf ~sync` the effect was `rm -rf /bin`, which pretty much trashes the system.

If you want to access the file itself, either quote it, or prefix it with something, such as its path:

```
$ cat ./~sync
```

You should also rework your code so that it does not create filenames that start with a tilde. This will save you and future you a lot of headaches later.

Comment: Wow. Yes, this is all correct and amazing. I knew about ~ being home, but in 20 years I NEVER knew about ~<user>. This seems like the perfect storm: a user named sync, me choosing sync for a filename, me choosing to code it to ~sync while working. All of it. Thank you thank you thank you!

I will rework the code and filenames.